# upload bitmap to server android using http post. need help in php script

Tags: java, php, android, upload

i am developing a android project 
i need to upload a bitmap on the apache server using a php script
method i am using is as follows

```
public void doFileUpload(Bitmap bitmapOrg) {
        InputStream is;

        ByteArrayOutputStream bao = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

        bitmapOrg.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, bao);

        byte [] ba = bao.toByteArray();

        String ba1= Base64.encodeToString(ba, 0);
        ArrayList<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<>();

        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("image",ba1));

        try{

            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();

            HttpPost httppost = new

                    HttpPost("http://172.17.0.250/upload.php");

            httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);

            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
            System.out.print(entity.toString());
            is = entity.getContent();

        }catch(Exception e){

            Log.e("log_tag", "Error in http connection " + e.toString());

        }

    }
```

and i donot know anything about php. i found this script for handling the file as follow.

```
<?php

$base=$_FILES['image'];

echo $base;

// base64 encoded utf-8 string

$binary=base64_decode($base);

// binary, utf-8 bytes

header('Content-Type: bitmap; charset=utf-8');

// print($binary);

//$theFile = base64_decode($image_data);

$file = fopen('test.jpg', 'wb');

fwrite($file, $binary);

fclose($file);

echo '<img src=test.jpg>';

?>
```

connection is getting established but i cant see any file in the /var/www/html/ directory. secondly i am not getting any message in the logcat.
i dont know what to do. i am a newbie to android and dont know anything about php. i understand java and core concepts of c, bash.kindly help me with the php scipt.

edit 1

as per the comments i have changed the php script to

```
<?php

    $file_path = "uploads/";

    $file_path = $file_path . basename( $_FILES['uploaded_file']['name']);
    if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploaded_file']['tmp_name'], $file_path)) {
        echo "success";
    } else{
        echo "fail";
    }
 ?>
```

and modified the method 
as

```
 HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();

            is = entity.getContent();
            System.out.println(is.read());
```

it is showing 102 in the log cat

Comment: i have also tried it using $base=$_REQUEST['image']; instead of $base=$_FILES['image'];  but did not work

Comment: where will the file be placed . do i need to chown(chan.ge owner) the php script

Comment: i have tested the script but it is not working.

Comment: is my android code ( method ) fine. i mean dry testing wise

Comment: The second php script is no good at all as the client does not upload your file in that way. Better take the first script again and change `$base=$_FILES['image'];` to `$base=$_POST['image'];` Remove `header('Content-Type: bitmap; charset=utf-8');`

Comment: Do you see these echo in your client? `echo $base;` and `echo '<img src=test.jpg>';` ? No. But that is because you do not read those echos from the InputStream is. You should do that. Just add a little code. That code has been published here often.

Comment: thanks for the comment .. i have done the same. getting byte stream in client. i think it is the full image. but still unable to find anything in the server(i mean file).

Comment: Show the used code.  `i think it is the full image. `. Wrong. You should be sure. It makes no sense to continue if you/we are not sure.

Comment: sir problem is solved....php script is unable to create a new file. if i place a test.jpeg image over there it is over writing the contents pretty fine.but i have given 777 permissions to the file. i dont know why php script is unable to create a new file but it can successfully overwriting the contents

Comment: How did you place that php script on the server? With ftp? Try with 755. It depends on your specific server and php version what is required.

Comment: 777 permission give read write and execute rights but 755 will not provide the write access to group and user .i have ssh access to the server and can simply login using a terminal

Comment: `but 755 will not provide the write access to group and user `. As stated before: if that is used depends also on php version. So try out with other combinations like 755.

Comment: that does not make any sense but i have tried same problem occured.

Comment: `but i have given 777 permissions to the file.` You should give that to the directory. (or 755 ;-).)

Comment: write it as a solution i will mark as solved

Comment: Please first tell how you made it possible. Unclear now.

Comment: sorry for late comment. i just created a new file at server named test.jpeg and assigned 777 permission to it. and my purpose solved